# Show that $\Delta = \{(y,y):y\in N\}\subset N\times N$ is a closed subset of $N\times N$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I have to show that

$$\Delta = \{(y,y):y\in N\}\subset N\times N$$ is a closed subset of $N\times N$

I can do this by showing that its complement is an open subset of $N\times N$, but a previous exercise in my list is the following:

Show that the graph of a continuous map $f:M\to N$ is a closed subset of $N\times N$

I think this exercise suggests me to think about the graph of $\Delta$. How can I say that $\Delta$ is a continuous map $f:M\to N$?

Comment: I guess you really mean $M\times N$ , although here $M=N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your $\Delta$ is the graph of the identity map
$$\operatorname{Id}_N :N\to N$$ with $\operatorname{Id}_N(n)=n$. That's a continuous map.

Comment: It's true that $\Delta$ is the graph of the identity map, but $\Delta$ need not be closed. In fact $\Delta$ is closed if and only if $N$ is a Hausdorff space. To give a counterexample, consider the indiscrete topological space on a two element set $N:=\{0,1\}$. Then, $N\times N$ is also indiscrete so that the only closed sets are $N\times N$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: @sqtrat: Every statement in this answer is correct. I never claimed $\Delta$ was closed. I'm furnishing hints according to the question posed by OP, given his comments. Obviously there is additional context which he has not revealed. Note too that OP accepted this answer. You should reconsider your downvote (I presume it was yours). Also, the "metric-spaces" tag was selected, so this suggests the space is indeed Hausdorff.

Comment: I never said you were wrong, but I missed the metric space tag and it was my downvote, so I'm sorry about that I'll remove it, since the OP had metric spaces in mind.

Comment: I can't seem to remove it, so if you perhaps edit the question(no need to really do anything), I will remove it.